# Laravel "Unable to locate a class or view for component" in production environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I develop on a Mac locally. Latest version of Big Sur.

Today I went to deploy my app to production via an Ubuntu server through Forge, and got greeted with an error I've never seen before, and can't find an answer to online. I can see MANY people complaining about it, but all anyone has said on other answers is link to issues that don't have solutions or even explanations really, so that's why I'm asking a new question.

The exact error is this;
`Unable to locate a class or view for component [layouts.base]. (View: /home/forge/default/releases/20201204084441/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)`

In my app I have;
`app\View\Components\Layouts\App.php`
which looks like this;

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Layouts;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class App extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('layouts.app');
    }
}
```

Then I also have;
`resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php`

```
<x-layouts.base>
<!-- contents -->
</x-layouts.base>
```

(Also pretty much the same for base)

Works flawlessly on Mac. As soon as I deploy it on Ubuntu, I get the error above that it is "unable to locate a class or view" with those names.

Can someone please instruct me on how I can go about fixing this, since so far I have absolutely no idea and despite knowing that case sensitivity is probably the issue as per the other questions about this, I cannot find any actual solution or way to resolve this.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Thanks for the suggestion but same issue/error. Can also trigger the same error by running `php artisan view:cache` on my server though. But if I run the same command on my Mac it completes successfully.

Comment: check in your ubuntu `views/layouts/app.blade.php` is this present ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes it is present.

Comment: in same folder `/home/forge/default/releases/20201204084441`?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yeah that one also has the layout files present as well.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. Thanks to your question, I could find out how to solve it :D

In my case, I had created a component inside another folder, for better organization sake:

```
$ php artisan make:component Tutorial/channelName/Alert
```

So it created the view component inside the following directory:

`views/components/tutorial/channel-name/alert.blade.php`

Now, to call your component you do it this way:

```
<x-tutorial.channelName.alert />
```

That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue and I fixed it by cross-checking my folder name.

Please note that the folder name should be `components` and not `component`.

**Refer the screenshot** for a better idea.

[image]

**Example:**

In case you are following the convention, one more thing is that if you have a file at

`views/components/admin/side-menu/side.blade.php`

You can call your Component as:

`<x-admin.side-menu.side></x-admin.side-menu.side>`

**Explained:**

The `x-` used in the blade syntax basically tells that you are selecting folder or file from the `Components` folder.

The `.` (dot) used is for every directory you dig to the blade file you want to use.

Comment: Took me way too long to figure out I named it component instead of components, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same problem but I realized that the error was the class name of the component. I didn't capitalize the class name and when I did capitalize the class name I stopped getting that error and my project worked well.

Please try capitalizing the class name that matches the component in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case, I didn't provide the namespace in the Component, it solved after providing namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for the mentioned problem is **case sensitive**,

for local looks like its case insensitive reasons its works for local perfect but breaks on serve.

if you have create new component inside any new folder
i.e

```
$ php artisan make:component Widgets/CustomAlert
```

it will create two files, class and blade file for the component.
class file

```
app\Views\Components\\CustomAlert.php
```

blade file

```
resources\views\components\widgets.custom-alert.blade.php
```

you can render component with either class or with blade file.
for class make sure folder, class name in case sensitive
ie.

```
<x-Widgets.CustomAlert />
```

to render blade file it should be

```
<x-widgets.custom-alert />
```

**Note**
if you have manually relocate the file, make sure your namespace in class file, filename and the component call syntax should be match(with case sensitive)

examples are just for reference try to compare syntax and names with your files,folder.

I hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems like youre missing the Components folder that comes with laravel inside the views folder , make sure you have that folder inside your file structure but if you dont then simply run the

```
composer update
```

it will add the components folder that youre missing alongside with other files that your project is missing

Answer (score 0):

when I was a beginner I got the same error But in my case, there is all ok but there is a small syntax error `<x- card />` there is a gap between card and dash which is not correct so there should be no space between dash and card `<x-card />` so try once maybe this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - solution
was to change:
`<x-forms.inputradio>`
to:
`<x-forms.inputRadio>`
just letter size..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had created a class `AppLogo` and I had the blade generated as `app-logo.blade.php`.

However, in my view files, I referenced the component as `x-applogo` and this worked locally, but in production (a live hosting server), I got this error.

SOLUTION:
I changed all occurrences of `x-applogo` in my blade/view files to `x-app-logo`.

This worked both in development and in production.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu after it working perfectly on mac and windows. I managed to get it to work by in my case replacing

```
<x-header />
```

with

```
<?php
$header = new header;
echo $header->render();
?>
```

and including at the top

```
use App\Views\Components\header;
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been solved with composer autoload.So, if you recently updated composer then use this:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have had this issue couple of times. Each time the reason was my inattentiveness. I.e. `x-frontend-layouts-services` instead of `x-frontend.layouts.services`. So be sure to check everything carefully

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had another component in my component blade.php file which didn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

This happens at server. try not to make components inside folder..
i had the same issue at server but did not get any solution,
the only solution worked is to keep your components outside any sub folder